# How to free space after deleting the millions of rows from a table

Tags: oracle

I performed a delete operation on my table . It deleted around 10 millions of rows from it

How do I free the space associated with the deleted data.

I used the query:

```
alter table tablename shrink space;
```

But it did not work for me. Do I need to concern about the index's associated with the table?

If that is the case, how do I need to do it.

Comment: try moving the table to another tablespace and back.

Comment: @benoit : I dont have an another tablespace to move the contents of  a table.I need to free the space using the alter command. I tried to understand the alter index coalesce command but couldnt figure out it.

Comment: @Raghavendar - Can you define "did not work"?  Did you get an error?  If so, what error?  If you did not get an error, what exactly did not work?  Are you looking at tablespace usage or data file usage statistics, for example?

Answer (score 5):

```
alter table TABLENAME move;
```

followed by rebuilding the indexes on that table should do what you want.

After 'moving' the table around, the indexes for the rows will become unusable (as you can verify with something like):

```
select index_name, status from all_indexes 
 where table_name = 'TABLENAME' and
       owner      = 'SOMEUSER';
```

So, you would rebuild such an *unusable* index with a

```
alter index TABLENAME_IX_01 rebuild;
```

Comment: I tried the way you suggested me but I am getting an error similar to below: ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 8192 in tablespace name When I try to add space the tablespace, I am getting an error. Please advise on adding space to the tablespace

Answer (score 2):

You do this, provided tablespace is ASSM:

```
alter table tablename enable row movement;

alter table tablename shrink space cascade;
```

Comment: Is it all right to keep row movement enabled or would it be a better idea to disable it after the shrinking?

Answer (score 1):

Might be helpful:

- [Reclaiming Wasted Space](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schema003.htm)
- [Reclaiming Oracle disk space](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_reclaiming_disk_space.htm)